# How to make Maven resolver for Shrinkwrap work?

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I have this code:

```
@Deployment(name = "default")
public static WebArchive getTestArchive() {
    File[] file = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("../pom.xml")
            .importCompileAndRuntimeDependencies()
            .resolve("org.restlet.gae:org.restlet").withTransitivity().asFile();
    System.out.println("FILE>>>>>>>>" + file.toString());
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "simple.war")
            .addClass(org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.class)
            .setWebXML("web.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("appengine-web.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("logging.properties");
}
```

**However when the test is run it throws this error:**

```
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.ResolutionException: Unable to get version for dependency specified by org.restlet.gae:org.restlet:compile, it was not provided in neither <dependencyManagement> nor <dependencies> sections.
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.task.ResolveVersionFromMetadataTask.execute(ResolveVersionFromMetadataTask.java:91)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.PomEquippedResolveStageBaseImpl.resolveVersion(PomEquippedResolveStageBaseImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.ResolveStageBaseImpl.resolveDependency(ResolveStageBaseImpl.java:189)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.ResolveStageBaseImpl.resolveDependency(ResolveStageBaseImpl.java:184)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.ResolveStageBaseImpl.resolve(ResolveStageBaseImpl.java:78)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.ResolveStageBaseImpl.resolve(ResolveStageBaseImpl.java:43)
    ... 58 more
```

My goal is that all the dependencies of the POM to be resolved so (hopefully) the Restlet arquillian test would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind your error seems pretty obvious. Your code is lacking a version number of the restlet artifact.

It should looks like:

```
 File[] file = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("../pom.xml")
            .importCompileAndRuntimeDependencies()
            .resolve("org.restlet.gae:org.restlet:2.3.0")  // Notice version number
            .withTransitivity().asFile();
```

Alternatively you can specify version inside `<dependencyManagement>` section, but your error message tells, that you forgot about it also.